# Can't log in to FaceTime

Tags: mac, apple-id, facetime

I have a problem with FaceTime. On my MacBook, when I try to log in into my FaceTime  it says `Your Apple ID "my e-mail-address" can not be used for FaceTime`.

Now, on my iPad & iPhone it does work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to try.

1. In System Preferences > iCloud, log out and then log back in.
2. If that doesn't work, contact Apple Support, per [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24962570#24962570) in the Apple Discussion Forums:

   > You need to call Apple. The problem is NOT on your end! I spoke with an Apple representative and they said that it is a "registration issue" and that THEY need to reset security settings. I waited 14 minutes but the representative found the issue then reset it and I was able to sign in.
   >
   > Call 1-800-275-2273 (It's free in the US or on Skype if you're in Europe!)  When you call, you'll get the standard automated secretary.  DO NOT SAY ANYTHING.  If you say anything, you will be told that you either need to purchase a protection plan for $19.99 or literally "end the call". Just stay on the line until you're asked if you wish to speak with a representative. Do that and you'll be connected (for free).  They will ask for you Macbook Pro serial number and a "Customer Code" if you have one.  Tell them how long that you've had this issue and they'll confirm your Apple ID.
   >
   > Once they confirm your Apple ID, they reset everything on their end and you should be set. Make sure that you are able to send messages/make calls before hanging up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a two-step authentication enabled for my apple id. 
So it was asking for app-specific password. I generated it on appleid.apple.com and used that as a password instead of password of my account and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

What I did when my FaceTime was acting up I updated my software. So that would help.

Comment: What exactly did you update?